Why does never extend object
type N = never
type T = N extends object ? true : false
//   ^? // type T = true

That doesn't make sense to me- I expect never to not extend anything. What am I missing?

never extends every type. X extends Y means (roughly) "X is a subtype of Y" Since there are no values of type never, it is trivially true that every value of type never is also a value of type object. So never extends object.  See linked q/a for more info.
